# "Query not understandable"- Using NOT in a pages view search

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

When using the NOT operator an error occurs.
QueryString example:

> Cat **AND** Dog **NOT** Fish

QueryString that works:

> Cat **AND** Dog **AND** ***NOT*** Fish

According to help the **NOT** should be replaced with **AND NOT** by Domino

[http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.notes85.help.doc%2Fsch_refine_query_r.html](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.notes85.help.doc/sch_refine_query_r.html)

Server returns following error:

> Query not understandable

Is this a bug or am I missing the point?

Obviously you could do as the example that works but most users will not

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a bug. The help document is very explicit. It says you cannot put NOT in between search terms. Train your users accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

According to the help it is clear that this string, cat NOT dog, should be replaced by domino with this string, cat AND NOT dog, so it is clearly a bug.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.notes.help.doc/DOC/H_TO_USE_SEARCH_OPERATORS_STEPS.html?resultof=%22%71%75%65%72%79%22%20%22%6f%70%65%72%61%74%6f%72%73%22%20